# Movable Type Administration to https subdomain

Tags: ssl, content-management-system, https, movabletype

I have working https protocol on my subdomain. I would like to change current url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi
```

**to**

```
https://ssl.mydomain.com/
```

How can I do it? Could anybody help me step by step? I am beginner in this field. I tried Google and also Movable Type forum, but no answer so far. Maybe this could help you http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/config-directives/admincgipath.html. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

The [AdminCGIPath](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/config-directives/admincgipath.html) config directive is exactly what you need to apply.

Assuming that you have already set up SSL with your hosting provider and placed your MT application files in the correct web root for the SSL domain (which can be the same domain as your main site), here are the steps to change the MT admin path to use the SSL

1. Open the mt-config.cgi file.
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   AdminCGIPath https://ssl.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi
   ```
3. Save the mt-config.cgi file.

   At this point you should be able to access MT via SSL by going to: https://ssl.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi
4. Rather than access MT at the root of this domain--which I don't suggest because you may want to host other SSL apps--I suggest that you place a redirect script in your index file.

   You can do this with [Meta Refresh Tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) or [html meta refresh](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm)

That should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! I realized too late that I haven't installed MT in my subdomain folder. Now everything works! Movable Type 5.01 is excellent. You are doing really great job.

I found a bug in wysiwyg and category widget at new/manage entry page. I can't edit or type anything (entry body). I also tried to change wysiwyg editor, but nothing happened. Are you aware of this issue or is it only my problem?

Also thank you for your quick response.